# Splitting data into rows and columns in VueJS

Tags: spring, vue.js, axios

I have some data and I am trying to figure out how I can display it in table format in rows and columns in `Vue Js`. The display should be as shown:

[image]

this is my code but only displays in one column only but need to split the data into rows and columns

```
<table>
<tbody> 
  <tr v-for="product in products">
        <td>{{product.item_name}}</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please share some of your code.

Comment: This is my code but only displays as one column <table>
<tbody> 
  <tr v-for="product in products">
  <td>{{product.item_name}}</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

Comment: OK. So split your array into subarrays. Then loop through the sub array. Each sub-array will be a row. Each element will be a cell.

Answer (score 1):

Using this function you can sort the initial array to be in three sections: (Make it a `vue` method).

```js
function sortList(list, rows) {
    const sortedList = [];

    let rowIndex = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        sortedList[i] = [];
    }

    list.forEach(item => {
        sortedList[rowIndex++].push(item);

        if ((rowIndex + 1) === rows) {
            rowIndex = 0;
        }
    });

    return sortedList;
}
```

Then you can set:

```
this.products = this.sortList(list, 3);
```

`list` being the initial array and `3` being the number of rows you want.

Then in the `template` you can do:

```html
<table>
    <tbody> 
        <tr v-for="row in products">
            <td v-for="item in row">{{ item.item_name }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```